# Solr Tokenizer that splits on case change

Tags: solr, solrj

I am looking for a tokenizer that splits text based on case change.
eg. indexing this text: "HandMade" will index hand and made so searching for hand or made will return results.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory - splitOnCaseChange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordDelimiterFilterFactory is what you want to use. It allows you to split on case change (as well as things like intra-word delimiters and numbers, depending on the arguments you use). See the docs here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

In your case, you should use `splitOnCaseChange="1"` to get what you want.